# Can't see google map in application anymore

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-2

I recently re-installed my windows and had to remove the old adb in order to run the application on my mobile device. My application uses google maps api v2 but now I can't see the map, only the zoom buttons. Do I need to get a new api key?

Comment: i guess you need to recreate the MapKey in order to be able to see the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your previous API key was linked to the debug key in you debug keystore located at:

```
C:\Users\<username>\.android\debug.keystore
```

If you've wiped out that keystore by re-installing ADB then you need to get a new API key for that new debug key.

Comment: new debug key and new api key fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

You don't need new API key.

You may generate new SHA-1 from your current debug.keystore and attach it to the existing API key. Removing old SHA-1 is optional, but as you don't need it, you may remove it.